# vifm search files in subfolders

Tags: file-search, vifm

How can I search files just like with `/` command but recursively scanning subfolders?

Or maybe there are other approaches to get a list of files that match some pattern in the current folder including all subfolders.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### :find command

There is [:fin[d]](http://vifm.info/vimdoc.shtml#vifm-%3Afind) command for that. Internally it invokes `find` utility (this is configurable via ['findprg'](http://vifm.info/vimdoc.shtml#vifm-%27findprg%27) option), so you can do everything `find` is capable of. That said, in most cases the simple form of the command suffices:

```
:find *.sh
```

Note that by default argument is treated as regular file pattern (`-name` option of `find`), which is different from regular expressions accepted by `/`.  For searching via regexp, use:

```
:find -regex '.*_.*'
```

If you want to scan only specific subfolders, just select them before running the command and search will be limited only to those directories.

`:find` command brings up a menu with search results. If you want to process them like regular files (e.g. delete, copy, move), hit <kbd>b</kbd> to change list representation.

#### Alternative that uses `/`

Alternatively you can populate current view with list of files in all subdirectories with command like (see [%u](http://vifm.info/vimdoc.shtml#vifm-%25u)):

```
:!find%u
```

and then use `/`, although this might be less efficient.

Comment: Once I have selected a file from the search results, I enter the file's directory. That's nice, but how do I get back to the search results?

Comment: @MatthiasBraun Use [:copen](https://vifm.info/vimdoc.shtml#vifm-%3Acopen) command.